# Can I store user information to local storage using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, local-storage

I am working on one website and currently I am using a cookie to store necessary information used by the consoles, whenever the user log in.

I would like to store the user information from the login not ONLY to the cookie but in a local storage key as well when user logs in and logs out using c#.

Currently I am using javascript to store information in local storage. But same approach is possible with c#?

Please suggest me some way to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

C# executes on server while local storage is on the client side. So it is not possible to access local storage using C# directly. This could be done through JavaScript only.

Although you can write custom [HtmlHelper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) (C# code) that generates JavaScript for accessing local storage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Alex. It helps me to think different approach.